# UV Image Editor Display "Repeat Image" Zoom Problem

Tags: uv-image-editor

Working with the UV Editor, I have a UV map that is scaled much larger than the source texture. The intent is that it should repeat, and it does. The problem is that I can't see the image in the editor window to place UVs. I've checked the "Repeat Image" box in the Display tool window and it works... until I zoom out past about 3 or 4 levels. Then the window increasingly fails to repeat until it's just a sliver in the lower left corner.

[image: UV Editor Display Repeat Image Display]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

This is in Blender 2.82a, Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing the loop on this one. Apparently, this is considered "expected behavior" for the moment. There is a .25 second window during which the graphics are allowed to be drawn. Past that time, rendering of the image stops to avoid bottlenecking the system or causing it to bog down.

While that is surely valid, it means that using small textures repeated lots of times and UV-mapping it over a large area (such as tiles on a huge roof, for example) is not possible.